# Occasionally X fails to load

Tags: boot, 13.04, xorg

While this usually happens after a kernel update, sometimes I my computer intermittently fails to load x.

It stops at tty6 so I believe it's just x failing to load. While I was in tty6 I copied the .log x org pointed me too. I read the errors.

http://pastebin.com/wjjifa21

What stands out is the system doesn't have permission to load a specific intel module. I took a snippet of the output from where I saw the first error. I can upload the entire log file if it makes diagnostic easier.

The strange thing, is I'll reboot and x will either load fine or, if it was just after a kernel upgrade (from ubuntu repos) I will have to boot into my previous kernel once before loading the new kernel.

EDIT:
I'm using an Ivy Bridge notebook, I disabled my nvidia gpu and am only using HD 4000 graphics.

Comment: This could be a driver issue. What graphics driver (ATI, nvidia, ...) are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to include that. I'm using the default Intel drivers on Ivy Bridge. Intel HD 4k graphics.

Comment: Try reinstalling your drivers and see if the problem persists

Comment: @JorenHammudoglu can I do this with $ dpkg-reconfigure mesa?

Comment: This [link](http://theclonker.de/?p=89) will help you reinstall your graphic drivers.

Comment: @Joren I logged into the shell, used ppapurge to purge the intel graphics stable ppa. Reinstalled by running that script. I added intel's ppa again, updated and installed updates then rebooted. So far so good, I will reply again or mark as solved depending on whether the issue comes back in the next few days. Before I tried this I noticed it was failing to detect screen0, the laptop screen. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I purged and reinstalled Intels graphics stack using the link Joren linked here:
http://theclonker.de/?p=89

I then manually reinstalled each package the script removed using apt-get in ubuntu's main repos and rebooted.

Once on a working desktop I used their 2013q2 graphics installer to get the latest graphics stack from 01.org. X has yet to fail on me, marking this as solved. Thanks for the help @Joren